# Is it possible to import a nested package to a matlab function

Tags: matlab, import, package

I have the following directories tree on my hard-drive:

> base_folder
>   base_folder\+primary_package
>   base_folder\+primary_package\+secondary_package

Assume under `primary_package` I have a function `foo` which calls a function `goo` that is stored in `secondary_package`.

Meaning I have the following files:

> base_folder\+primary_package\foo.m
>   base_folder\+primary_package\+secondary_package\goo.m

foo's implementation is:

```
 function [] = foo() 
       primary_package.secondary_package.goo();
 end
```

It works, but in practice I have many calls to many functions in `secondary_package` and it makes my code unreadable.

I tried the following which didn't work:

```
function [] = foo()    
      import primary_package.secondary_package.*;
      goo();
end
```

Is there a way of importing the nested package to avoid many very long lines in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import primary_package.secondary_package.*;
goo();
```

should work just fine. At least it works for me.

**EDIT:** make sure that `base_folder` is in your `path`.